# Rename kafka consumer group in Sarama?

Tags: go, apache-kafka, sarama

I have a use case in which I want to rename the `consumer_group_2` to `consumer_group`. I want to do this because I want to start consuming from the last consumed offset of `consumer_group_2` but I want to rename the group id from `consumer_group` to `consumer_group_2`

Is it possible in [Sarama](https://github.com/Shopify/sarama/issues/1861) consumer group?

Answer (score 3):

You can't rename a consumer group.

You need to create a new consumer group and commit the same offsets as your other group. You do use the following:

- `admin.ListConsumerGroupOffsets()` to first retrieve offsets from the old group
- send an `OffsetCommitRequest` with the offsets and the new group
- `admin.DeleteConsumerGroup()` to delete the old group